# Voltage between two wires?

Tags: voltage

In my textbook we are given the question below. I understand how to get the answer of B. But I am confused as to why the answer of A is 10 volts where the difference is 20 volts.. 10 and -10? Where is my logic or understanding wrong?

In your circuit, two wires connected to a 10-V voltage supply happen to be very close to each other at a certain location; they are separated by 2 mm.

- A. What is the voltage between the wires at this location?

> Wouldn't the difference be 20 V? But the answer key says 10 V, why is
>   this?

- B. What is approximately the electric field strength at this
  location?

> (Answer A) / .002 = ..

Comment: I may be misreading the problem, but it sounds like the two wires are connected to +10V and ground (0V), not -10V.

Comment: But does my logic sound right, from the way I am reading it?

Comment: Where does the -10 V come from? Drawing a schematic may help understanding.

Comment: I'd have said A is 0 V. Because if you just say "a wire is connected to a 10 V source", I assume you mean it's connected to the positive terminal, and the other terminal is considered ground. Since the two wires are both connected to the same terminal of the source, there's no voltage between them.

Comment: A 10V supply has two output terminals, and creates 10V between the terminals, and you connect a wire to each terminal, so there is 10V between the wires.

Comment: @John No, if engineers are talking about voltage sources, the voltage of that source always describes the potential difference between both terminals. If it is the only voltage source around in a simple resistive environment, there can't be a higher voltage than the difference of the potentials, which we call "the voltage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two wires connected to a voltage source of 10V (the polarity is of no importance here) have the same voltage over the whole length under the following conditions.

1. There is no flow of current (Not mentioned in the question).

Think also of this.

If there was a current you would need also the resistance of the wire expressed in Ohm/m and the distance of the 2 mm spot from the source.

2. They do not touch each other (2mm distance as in the question)

Remember that the expression of fieldstrengh is V/m

The field strengh depends on the voltage and distance. Therefore in the question we have 10V/2mm = 5000 V/m.

Comment: @John. Happy with my answer. Please upvote also